# please assist in executing the procedure

Tags: t-sql

Could you please assist in executing this procedure please .

**Canot execute this procedure** , 
however procedure run successfully without errors

```
                exec iso.proc_Additem('12345')

                And 

               **Canot insert values** 

              insert into tbl_Handle 
              values(SYSTEM_USER,DATE)
```

### sql stored procedure is

```
           --Procedure Add item to the list --

 Create procedure iso.proc_Additem

@card_id  nvarchar(50) ,
@card_type  nvarchar(1) = 'N'

          AS 
          BEGIN

          Begin transaction 

         Insert into iisr.tbl_handle
         (  UserName )
         Values
         ( system_user )
```

**-Comented --Table definition** create table iso.tbl_Handle

```
        ( Handle int identity(1,1) 
         , UserName nvarchar(50)
         , Created date
         , constraint pk_Handle primary key(Handle)

        );--
```

**/* Get Handle */**

```
         declare @Card_Handle int  

         SELECT @Card_Handle = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  -- get handle

          Insert into iso.tbl_card_list
          ( Card_ID , card_type ) 
          Values
          (@Card_ID,@Card_Type)
```

-**comented --table definition** iso.tbl_card_list

```
              CREATE TABLE iso.tbl_card_list
              ( Card_Handle int
              , Card_ID nvarchar(50) not null
              , Card_Type char(1) Default 'N' not null
              , Delete_handle int not null
              , Constraint PK_Card_List Primary Key ( Card_Handle) 
              , Constraint FK_1 foreign key (Card_Handle) references iso.tbl_Handle     (Handle)  
              , Constraint FK_2 foreign key(delete_Handle)references iso.tbl_Handle(Handle)
              , Constraint CK_1 check (Card_Type in ('N','T')));--


                      Commit transaction

                        End
```

---

Comment: What error message do you get and what part of the code is generating that error?

Comment: Stored procedure executed without errors but trouble calling the procedure  : exec iso.proc_additem ('1234','n')

Comment: What error do you get when calling the SP?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis. You call the SP like this.

```
exec iso.proc_Additem '12345', 'n'
```

Comment: (1 row(s) affected) Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure proc_Additem, Line 22 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Card_Handle', table 'iso.tbl_card_list'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The error pretty much explains what is wrong. `tbl_card_list` needs a `Card_Handle` and you are not providing one in the insert statement. BTW, it also needs a `Delete_handle`.

Comment: error coming up is : procedure has too many arguments specified , when i add onother parameter for card_handle :card_handle is identity : scope_identity(0 function auto numbers : could you please clarify me calling procedure ? exec '1234','n','@card_handle ','@delete_handle ') ?

Comment: You can't fix this in the call to the SP. You need to modify the insert statement in the SP.

Comment: I added delete_handle in the insert statement  of SP Insert into iso.tbl_card_list ( Card_ID , card_type,Delete_handle ) Values (@Card_ID,@Card_Type,0): when am calling this procedure again insert failed due to conflict with foreign key in the table tbl)handle ,column handle

Comment: I told you to add both `Card_Handle` **and** `Delete_handle`. Also I don't think a 0 for `Delete_Handle` will work since you have a FK against `tbl_Handle`. Perhaps it is a mistake to have `not null` on `Delete_Handle` in `tbl_card_list`?

Comment: thank you , i can call the procedure now  .